# Sprinng-aop @Around is not working as expected

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-aop

I have written a simple AOP to log request and execution time.
Everything working fine, but while using the annotation to log the execution time it's not retuning any response though http status code is 200.

Could you please let me know what is the issue ?

**Controller:**

```
@LogExecutionTime
@GetMapping("/test")
public String index(){
   return "Hello";
}
```

**Aspect:**

```
@Around("@annotation(LogExecutionTime)")
public void logTime(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) throws Throwable{
  watch.start() // common lang stopwatch
  jp.proceed();
  watch.stop();

 log,info("Execution time " +watch);
}
```

in log I can see it's showing the execution time but in postman I am  **not** getting the response "hello"
if I comment the @LogExecutionTime annotation it's working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aspects of type "around" have the ability to modify the return value. The `proceed` method returns the value from the original method, which you are silently ignoring, and opting to not return anything (which I believe then defaults the call to returning null). You need to modify your method as follows:

```java
@Around("@annotation(LogExecutionTime)")
public Object logTime(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) throws Throwable{
  watch.start(); // common lang stopwatch
  Object returnValue = jp.proceed();
  watch.stop();

  log.info("Execution time " +watch);

  return returnValue;
}
```

You might additionally want to place your `watch.stop()` call in a `finally` block in case the observed method throws an exception.

Comment: a same doubt, I gave another method which is annotated with '@Before', but when my controller raising any exception against '@Valid' RequestBody, this '@Before' part is not executing, what is the reason ?

Comment: I would recommend you post a new question for that issue. It's hard to examine without more context and the comments section isn't really suitable for that